# Rails intranet apps running on machines with no internet access have long page load times.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails intranet application that is running solely behind our firewall. As we started to deploy we found that the application is taking between 30 seconds and a minute and  a half to load and to execute things such a a logon. On any machine we tested that had internet access, the load times were almost instantaneous. On machines that are restricted from internet access, we are experiencing unusable load times.

I ran wireshark on my machine (internet access) and found very little traffic outside of our network. However, I did see traffic to 23.49.240.54 which resolves to the Akamai distribution network. I remembered that I had two calls to :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

I'm going to do some more testing but my guess is that this might be the cause of the delay. I am trying to see if the firewall admin can allow ajax.googleapis.com through for the restricted IP machines.

Does it seem logical that the issue with the delay is called by this call?   The odd thing is that the app eventually works with no apparent loss of functionality even where I am using jquery. I would have expected an error.

Is there a way to use a local copy of the google ajax libraries?

Comment: You can use `jquery gem` and `jquery-ui gem` inside your app to have this libraries available.

Comment: Apparently I had the gems AND the google api calls. I removed the google api calls and everything is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's probably trying to make the external api call, waiting a set amount of time for a response, then timing out and allowing the application to proceed. As mentioned in the comments by Chris, you might be able to just download the jquery gems to get this functionality.

You should definitely remove the API call though, for every user that visits the page this API is being called, waits a while and then fails. That's a lot of waste.

Comment: Just did that. As I stated above, I already had the gems AND api calls. Now it is just using the gems.